# How to add data from link click to form field

Tags: jquery, forms, hyperlink

I'm building a site that offers a number of downloads in return for email addresses. When each of the downloads are clicked it brings up a pop-up form where the user can enter their email address to get their download.

Something like this (https://jsfiddle.net/8frqbgmz/):

```
<!-- LINKS -->
<a href="#1">Download #1</a>
<a href="#2">Download #2</a>
<a href="#3">Download #3</a>

<!-- FORM -->
<form>
    <label for="link">Link that's been clicked:</label>
    <input type="text" name="link">
</form>
```

What I'd like to do is populate this 'link' field with the details of which of the links the user has clicked on.

I'm guessing this may be done by adding some extra info to each of the links and then creating a script that populates the 'link' field with the info when the link is clicked, but I've no idea how to do that.

Any ideas would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Maybe take a look at [bootstrap modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/modal/)

Comment: I added a simple JS example to your fiddle, maybe that'll gives you a hint: https://jsfiddle.net/c1j9wa64/2/

Comment: To add to Steffen's fiddle you'd probably want to `preventDefault()` and catch the href in the jQuery on click. You can then capture the href to both display it exactly how Steffen has it, and also spawn the download from another window perhaps using `window.location.assign(href)` or `window.open(href)`

Comment: That's really helpful everyone, especially @Steffen Roßkamp. I've added my exact solution below in case it helps anyone else in future.

Answer (score 0):

Cracked it thanks to Steffen's comment above.

Here's a fiddle and code snippet showing the solution that worked for me, hopefully it helps someone else looking to do the same in the future:

https://jsfiddle.net/L271scn9/1/

```
<!-- LINKS -->
<a href="#ebooks_form_popup" id="Title of the first ebook" class="fancybox_no_padding visible_link">Download for free</a><br>
<a href="#ebooks_form_popup" id="Title of the second ebook" class="fancybox_no_padding visible_link">Download for free</a><br>
<a href="#ebooks_form_popup" id="Title of the third ebook" class="fancybox_no_padding visible_link">Download for free</a><br><br>

<!-- FORM -->
<form>
    <label for="email">Email Address:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
    <label for="link">Link that's been clicked:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="link">
</form>

<!-- SCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("a.visible_link").on("click", function(event) {
            $("[name=\"nf-field-33\"]").val(event.target.id);
        });
    });
</script>
```